# RMI Object already exported

Tags: java, rmi

I am having an issue trying to get RMI working. I have the registry running, when I try start the server a window pops up for less than a second and then closes. Why is this happening.

Server package --- MyFileServer.java

```
package Server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

/**
 * Created by alexi on 05/12/2016.
 */
public class MyFileServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInit {



    protected  MyFileServer() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void importFiles(Notify n, String name) throws RemoteException {
        String videoPath = "src" + File.separator + "Videos" + File.separator + name;
        try {

            File video = new File(videoPath);
            FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(video);
            byte [] mydata=new byte[(int)video.length()+1];
            int mylen=in.read(mydata);
            while(mylen>0){
                n.sendData(video.getName(), mydata, mylen);
                mylen=in.read(mydata);
            }

        }catch( Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerInit server = new MyFileServer();
            ServerInit stub = (ServerInit) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("videoServer", stub);

        }catch (RemoteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Running it like so.

```
start java -classpath E:\Documents\Development\Projects\OOP3_Project1\bin\Server/ -Djava.rmi.codebase=file:/E:\Documents\Development\Projects\OOP3_Project1\bin\Server/ MyFileServer
```

If someone could help would be great

Comment: Don't keep changing your question as solutions develop.

Comment: @EJP what are you talking about I only changed the title . Content is still the same

Comment: You changed the title to something totally vague, which left the question meaning absolutely nothing, as there is no other hint in the question as to what the actual problem or error message was.

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` line. You only need that if your remote object doesn't extend `UnicastRemoteObject`. You can bind `server` instead of the stub.

Comment: Hey thanks.Still closes immediately after i execute.

Comment: But with a different exception.